# Need help with cURL request

Tags: php, session, cookies, post, curl

I need some help with setting up a cURL request to a page. In the netherlands we have this site 'RDW.NL' which gives you the opportunity to check up a vehicle's details by entering the licence plate number.

For businesses, there is a paid alternative to request large amounts of data, but the costs are too high (€1050 + €0,50 per request) to pay this since it's just for personal use and for testing purposes only.

Recently they changed their website and the old scripts stopped working, so I decided to give it a try myself but I'm kind of stuck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $ckfile = "/tmp/rdwcookie.txt";

    # Setup first URL
    $ch = curl_init("https://ovi.rdw.nl/Default.aspx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile); 
    $input = curl_exec($ch);

    # Get VIEWSTATE variable
    preg_match('/id="__VIEWSTATE" value="(.*)" \/>/i', $input, $__VIEWSTATE);   
    preg_match('/Set-Cookie: ISAWPLB{(.*)}={(.*)};/i', $input, $__COOKIES);
    preg_match('/Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=(.*);/i', $input, $__ASPNET);

    #echo $input;

    # Set options for RDW Call
    $options = array(
        'ctl00$ctl00$PlaceHolderMainContent$PlaceHolderMainContent$txtKenteken' => '16-JS-GK',
        'ctl00%24ctl00%24PlaceHolderMainContent%24PlaceHolderMainContent%24btnZoeken' => 'Zoeken',
        '__VIEWSTATE' => $__VIEWSTATE[1],
        '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => ''
    );

    #echo file_get_contents($ckfile);

    # Setup second URL
    $ch = curl_init("https://ovi.rdw.nl/VoertuigDetails.aspx");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $options);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'ISAWPLB{'.$__COOKIES[1].'}='.$__COOKIES[2].'; ASP.NET_SessionId='.$__ASPNET[1]);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    # Echo data 
    echo $data;

?>
```

At the first page I try to save all cookies (which works), but sending the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE does not show up any cookies in the headers of the cURL request. Therefor I used CURLOPT_COOKIE with some preg_matches to get the cookies manually and send them along (this works).

Also the post variables are right.

However, it still complains that the service is offline when I echo `$data`, this could be the case of course, but when visiting the page and entering some data manually it works perfectly.

So, is there something I'm missing? I can't seem to get the right page loaded with cURL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used a different source, the SSL was interfering with getting the right response. It works properly with the given example. Thanks for thinking tho.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any redirection which curl may not follow? Specially in php safe-mode php will not follow redirects causing curl_exec return empty string.
Check for safe mode and location: headers in your raw response.

Comment: the response isn't empty. It returns the page, but I must be missing some session/cookie/header information for the page to load correctly. It gives a vague error (service not online) but when visiting the page by browser shows me that the page is working like it should.